# How to get relative path of an exe in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, path, package

I have a config class that references a chromedriver.exe file via a String path like so

```
public static final String CHROMEDRIVER_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Users\\asdf\\Desktop\\Testing\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe";
```

That code is located in the src folder while the chromedriver.exe is located in a separate drivers folder. The project layout looks something like this.

Testing

1. src -> constants package -> config
2. drivers -> chromedriver.exe

How can I edit the string so that it can find the chromedriver without having to type the absolute path? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "drivers\\chromedriver.exe".

Comment: that worked! i thought you would need to navigate a few times upwards to get to the same directory level as drivers, then go into the drivers directory?

Comment: You're welcome :) Probably the first directory level is project root.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your chromedriver.exe in one folder in your current project directory(say **win**). Then use

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "win" + File.separator + "chromedriver.exe"
```